# Seek Compact. Easiness to configure and use

Tags: pi-3, camera, pi-zero-w

Hello everyone and happy new year.
I'm in need of a thermal camera for my project. I am considering buying a FLIR Lepton but just found out that you can use a Seek camera with the Pi as well which would be cheaper.
My question is, does anyone have any experience setting up the Seek camera as to how easy it was to get it working and what results did you get?
Thanks in advance

Comment: OK then, I install dependencies with sudo apt-get or other way, download the files from github, compile with make and then run software either by double clicking a file or with sudo ./whatever_the_file.

Comment: Please don't add additional information in comments. Instead click the [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/106853/edit) link beneath the question and add it there.

Comment: I only added that info because someone told me to.